# C++ - circular dependence (using inner type of subclass in templated base class)

Tags: c++, templates, circular-dependency, crtp, incomplete-type

I run into problem with circular dependence in a templated class. There is a code sample:

```
template <typename T> struct A 
{
  typedef typename T::C D;
  //typename T::C c;
};

struct B : public A<B>
{
  struct C {};
};
```

When I try to instantiate B, I get a compiler error: *'C' is not a member of 'B'* (MSVC) or  *Invalid use of incomplete type 'struct B'* (GCC).
What is the best way to change the sample to get it to work?

Comment: You can't. Provide a slightly more complete example of the problem you're trying to solve, and we can look at refactoring the code.

Answer (score 6):

```
struct B_base { struct C {}; };
strucr B : A<B_base>, B_base { };
```

Comment: May not be helpful if `A` is a CRTP template which puts the parameter type `T` in member declarations.  In that case, you'll probably just have to make `C` an additional template parameter.